# IP2country lite fails to down load data

Tags: vb.net

I've been using IP2Country Lite for some time now without issue. I use an app to periodically download the CSV and  load it into my DB. Having made some change in my program I was doing some testing and ended up getting
"THIS FILE CAN ONLY BE DOWNLOADED 5 TIMES PER HOUR"
I quite for a while and tried again the next day and still get the same error. I can log on to the web site manually and download the data but my application is unsuccessful. Anybody have an idea?

Thanks Nor